# MongoDB sort with specific id

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I have a list of data in Mongo that I need to sort based on a user's inputted value.

For example, I have the following data:

```
CityId, Price
3, 200
5, 100
1, 50
5, 40
9, 10
5, 75
8, 1000
```

I want to return first specific cityId then price like OrderByDescending(c => c.CityId==5).ThenByDescending(c=>c.Price)

```
CityId, Price
5, 100
5, 75
5, 40
8, 1000
3, 200
1, 50
9, 10
```

I tried:

```
 var builder = Builders<T>.Sort;
 var sort = builder.Descending("CityId").Descending("Price");
 var result= GetCollection().Find(customFilter).Sort(sort).ToList();
```

But I need like :

```
 var builder = Builders<T>.Sort;
 //var sort = builder.Descending("CityId"==5).Descending("Price");  ?????
 var result= GetCollection().Find(customFilter).Sort(sort).ToList();
```

How can I sort ?

Comment: Your sample output is not in any descending order for CityId. If you just want to select CityId == 5 and then sort the results by Price descending, then you should require that CityId is 5 in your custom filter.

Comment: @Klaycon I need all records.First must come cityId=5 records. After(thenby order price) I have pagination I can't do two GetCollection(first only cityID==5)
And how can I sort only by value like Descending("CityId"==5)

Comment: "First all rows with specific value from one column, then all other rows ordered by another column" is not a typical sorting method, nor one easily accomplishable in MongoDB. I suggest you take the result list and order it that way manually using e.g. Linq: `result = result.FindAll(r => r.CityId == 5).Concat(result.FindAll(r => r.CityId != 5).OrderByDescending(r => r.Price))`